# How to apply filters while reading all the json files from a folder using scala?

Tags: apache-spark-2.0

I have folder which has multiple json files(first.json, second.json) .Using scala i am loading all the jsonfiles data to rdd/dataset of spark and then applying filter on the data.

The problem here is if we have 600 of data then we need to load all of them into rdd/dataset and then we are applying filter

looking for a solution where i can filter the records while reading from the folder itself and not loading into spark memory.

Filtering is done based on blockheight property.

Json structure in each file :

### first.json :

[{"IsFee":false,"BlockDateTime":"2015-10-14T09:02:46","Address":"0xe8fdc802e721426e0422d18d371ab59a41ddaeac","BlockHeight":381859,"Type":"IN","Value":0.61609232637203584,"TransactionHash":"0xe6fc01ff633b4170e0c8f2df7db717e0608f8aaf62e6fbf65232a7009b53da4e","UserName":null,"ProjectName":null,"CreatedUser":null,"Id":0,"CreatedUserId":0,"CreatedTime":"2019-08-26T22:32:45.2686137+05:30","UpdatedUserId":0,"UpdatedTime":"2019-08-26T22:32:45.2696126+05:30"},{"IsFee":false,"BlockDateTime":"2015-10-14T09:02:46","Address":"0x52bc44d5378309ee2abf1539bf71de1b7d7be3b5","BlockHeight":381859,"Type":"OUT","Value":-0.61609232637203584,"TransactionHash":"0xe6fc01ff633b4170e0c8f2df7db717e0608f8aaf62e6fbf65232a7009b53da4e","UserName":null,"ProjectName":null,"CreatedUser":null,"Id":0,"CreatedUserId":0,"CreatedTime":"2019-08-26T22:32:45.3141203+05:30","UpdatedUserId":0,"UpdatedTime":"2019-08-26T22:32:45.3141203+05:30"}]

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object BalanceAndTransactionDownload {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("xxx").getOrCreate()

    val currencyDataSchema = StructType(Array(
        StructField("Type", StringType, true),
        StructField("TransactionHash", StringType, true),
        StructField("BlockHeight", LongType, true),
        StructField("BlockDateTime", TimestampType, true),
        StructField("Value", DecimalType(38, 18), true),
        StructField("Address", StringType, true),
        StructField("IsFee", BooleanType, true)
    ))

    val projectAddressesFile = args(0)
    val blockJSONFilesContainer = args(1)
    val balanceFolderName = args(2)
    val downloadFolderName = args(3)
    val blockHeight = args(4)
    val projectAddresses = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(projectAddressesFile)
    val currencyDataFile = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").schema(currencyDataSchema).json(blockJSONFilesContainer) // This is where i want to filter out the data
    val filteredcurrencyData = currencyDataFile.filter(currencyDataFile("BlockHeight") <= blockHeight)
    filteredcurrencyData.join(projectAddresses, filteredcurrencyData("Address") === projectAddresses("address")).groupBy(projectAddresses("address")).agg(sum("Value").alias("Value")).repartition(1).write.option("header", "true").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").csv(balanceFolderName)
    filteredcurrencyData.join(projectAddresses, filteredcurrencyData("Address") === projectAddresses("address")).drop(projectAddresses("address")).drop(projectAddresses("CurrencyId")).drop(projectAddresses("Id")).repartition(1).write.option("header", "true").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").csv(downloadFolderName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the files sitting on the datastore should be partitioned. u seem to filter by block height. so u can have multiple folders like: `blockheight=1`, `blockheight=2` etc.. and have json files inside these folders. inthis case spark will not read all json files it will instead scan the folders required.

Comment: Thanks Ravi for the heads up. But should i rename the folders as blockheight=1 or simply 1 , 2 .... 1000 and indide each folder i can have json files like inside folder 1 will have 1.json and folder 2 will have 2.json .

Please let me know if this works or i need to go with blockheight=1 and so on

Comment: `blockheight=1` . only when u create folders this way that they will be queriable by the predicate: `blockheight`. Each of the folders may have a json in any name; UUID also works. the name (1.json or just 1 or abc.json or just pqr) shouldnt matter. But make sure that the json files are related to the respective folder `blockheight=<>`